# Conditions for $C^{\infty}$-compatible charts to actually cover a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm studying about manifolds, and how to define a notion of differentiability, we require charts to be compatible. i.e. the transition maps between overlapping charts should be differentiable. I understand why this is required, but is it always necessary to reduce the maximal atlas to compatible charts such that the compatible charts **still** cover the entire manifold?

Is there extra structure that we have to impart to the manifold to ensure that the reduced number of charts still cover the manifold?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding computations on a manifold it is not so important consider the maximal atlas of the differential structure because it is extremely hard to compute it. In that case it is sufficient to exhibit a set of charts, belonging to that atlas, that cover the manifold, in order to have that set of charts is an atlas.

Why it is important to define a differential structure on the manifold, i.e. a maximal atlas?

This is important when you want to study different differential structures on the same manifolds. In fact it is not sufficient in general take two atlas on the same Manifold to say that they are two different differentiable structures on it. They will have two different structures if their union is not an atlas, so there are two charts that are not compatible.

For example $(\mathbb{R}, Id_{\mathbb{R}})$ and $(\mathbb{R}, x^3)$ are two different structures on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not entirely clear though on the conditions that cause a collection of compatible charts to be an atlas. I've heard that there are some manifolds on which the maximal atlas can be reduced to a differential atlas, on others it can't be. So the question is, what properties should a manifold have that guarantee the maximal atlas can be reduced to an **atlas** (not just any ordinary collection) of compatible maps?